# Group array of objects by a sub-property

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object which holds an array of objects loaded from the following JSON:

```
"accounts": [
{
  "name": "aa",

  "branch": {
        "id": 1
  }
}

{
  "name": "bb",

  "branch": {
        "id": 1
  }
}

{
  "name": "cc",

  "branch": {
        "id": 2
  }
}
]
```

I want to group these by the branch id. If i was grouping by "set", i simply do:

```
groupMap= _.groupBy(object, 'set');
```

And the first and last object are grouped together. But how would I group by a property of a property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a function to return a value, based on which the grouping will be done, like this

```
console.log(_.groupBy(obj.accounts, function(currentObject) {
    return currentObject.branch.id;
}));
```

**Output**

```
{
    '1': [{
        name: 'aa',
        branch: {
            id: 1
        }
    }, {
        name: 'bb',
        branch: {
            id: 1
        }
    }],
    '2': [{
        name: 'cc',
        branch: {
            id: 2
        }
    }]
}
```